Получение данных из 1С через brom
Всем привет! Возникла проблема при получении видов номенклатур через расширение Brom на Python
Вот мой код:
from brom import *

клиент = БромКлиент(
    публикация="http://localhost/BROM",
    пользователь="brom",
    пароль=""
)

клиент.Справочники.ВидыНоменклатуры.НайтиПоНименованию("Товары")

Вот ошибка:
{
    "name": "TransportError",
    "message": "Server returned response (400) with invalid XML: Invalid XML content received (Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1).
Content: b'\\xef\\xbb\\xbf{\"#exception\":\"{http://v8.1c.ru/8.1/data/core}Exception\",\"exception\":{\"clsid\":\"a01f465c-ed70-442e-ada5-847668d7a41c\",\"descr\":\"\\xd0\\x94\\xd0\\xbe\\xd1\\x81\\xd1\\x82\\xd0\\xb8\\xd0\\xb3\\xd0\\xbd\\xd1\\x83\\xd1\\x82\\xd0\\xbe \\xd0\\xbe\\xd0\\xb3\\xd1\\x80\\xd0\\xb0\\xd0\\xbd\\xd0\\xb8\\xd1\\x87\\xd0\\xb5\\xd0\\xbd\\xd0\\xb8\\xd0\\xb5 \\xd1\\x83\\xd1\\x87\\xd0\\xb5\\xd0\\xb1\\xd0\\xbd\\xd0\\xbe\\xd0\\xb9 \\xd0\\xb2\\xd0\\xb5\\xd1\\x80\\xd1\\x81\\xd0\\xb8\\xd0\\xb8\\\
\\xd0\\x94\\xd0\\xbe\\xd1\\x81\\xd1\\x82\\xd0\\xb8\\xd0\\xb3\\xd0\\xbd\\xd1\\x83\\xd1\\x82\\xd0\\xbe \\xd0\\xbf\\xd1\\x80\\xd0\\xb5\\xd0\\xb4\\xd0\\xb5\\xd0\\xbb\\xd1\\x8c\\xd0\\xbd\\xd0\\xbe\\xd0\\xb5 \\xd0\\xba\\xd0\\xbe\\xd0\\xbb\\xd0\\xb8\\xd1\\x87\\xd0\\xb5\\xd1\\x81\\xd1\\x82\\xd0\\xb2\\xd0\\xbe \\xd0\\xbf\\xd0\\xbe\\xd0\\xb4\\xd0\\xba\\xd0\\xbb\\xd1\\x8e\\xd1\\x87\\xd0\\xb5\\xd0\\xbd\\xd0\\xb8\\xd0\\xb9 \\xd0\\xba \\xd0\\x98\\xd0\\x91\",\"data\":\"77u/ew0Ke2EwMWY0NjVjLWVkNzAtNDQyZS1hZGE1LTg0NzY2OGQ3YTQxYywi0JTQ\\\\r\\\
vtGB0YLQuNCz0L3Rg9GC0L4g0L7Qs9GA0LDQvdC40YfQtdC90LjQtSDRg9GH0LXQ\\\\r\\\
sdC90L7QuSDQstC10YDRgdC40LgNCtCU0L7RgdGC0LjQs9C90YPRgtC+INC/0YDQ\\\\r\\\
tdC00LXQu9GM0L3QvtC1INC60L7Qu9C40YfQtdGB0YLQstC+INC/0L7QtNC60LvR\\\\r\\\
jtGH0LXQvdC40Lkg0Log0JjQkSIsDQp7MDAwMDAwMDAtMDAwMC0wMDAwLTAwMDAt\\\\r\\\
MDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwfSwiYmFja2VuZHQuZGxsOjB4MDAwMDZERDYgYmFja2VuZHQu\\\\r\\\
ZGxsOjB4MDA1OEMxQUUgYmFja2VuZHQuZGxsOjB4MDA1OEFERUYgdnJzYmFzZXQu\\\\r\\\
ZGxsOjB4MDAwMTgwQjQgdnJzYmFzZXQuZGxsOjB4MDAwMTcwMTMgdnJzYmFzZXQu\\\\r\\\
ZGxsOjB4MDAwMTY3MUUgdnJzYmFzZXQuZGxsOjB4MDAxMUZDRkUgdnJzYmFzZXQu\\\\r\\\
ZGxsOjB4MDAxMjBEQkUgdnJzYmFzZXQuZGxsOjB4MDAwNERFODMgdnJzYmFzZXQu\\\\r\\\
ZGxsOjB4MDAwMTMwODMgdnJzYmFzZXQuZGxsOjB4MDAwNTYxNzYgdnJzYmFzZXQu\\\\r\\\
ZGxsOjB4MDAwNEIyMDkgdnJzYmFzZXQuZGxsOjB4MDAwNTY0QTQgdnJzYmFzZXQu\\\\r\\\
ZGxsOjB4MDAwNTZFODkgY29yZTgzdC5kbGw6MHgwMDI3Q0EyMCBjb3JlODN0LmRs\\\\r\\\
bDoweDAwMjdDQTgyIGNvcmU4M3QuZGxsOjB4MDAxNThFMzQgdWNydGJhc2UuZGxs\\\\r\\\
OjB4MDAwMDAwMDAgS0VSTkVMMzIuRExMOjB4MDAwMDAwMDAgdW5rbm93bjoweDAw\\\\r\\\
MDAwMDAwIHVua25vd246MHgwMDAwMDAwMCAiLCIwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAw\\\\r\\\
MDAwMDAwIiwwMDAwMDAwMC0wMDAwLTAwMDAtMDAwMC0wMDAwMDAwMDAwMDB9LDM5\\\\r\\\
fQ==\",\"category\":\"0000000000000000000000000\",\"creationStack\":\"backendt.dll:0x00006DD6 backendt.dll:0x0058C1AE backendt.dll:0x0058ADEF vrsbaset.dll:0x000180B4 vrsbaset.dll:0x00017013 vrsbaset.dll:0x0001671E vrsbaset.dll:0x0011FCFE vrsbaset.dll:0x00120DBE vrsbaset.dll:0x0004DE83 vrsbaset.dll:0x00013083 vrsbaset.dll:0x00056176 vrsbaset.dll:0x0004B209 vrsbaset.dll:0x000564A4 vrsbaset.dll:0x00056E89 core83t.dll:0x0027CA20 core83t.dll:0x0027CA82 core83t.dll:0x00158E34 ucrtbase.dll:0x00000000 KERNEL32.DLL:0x00000000 unknown:0x00000000 unknown:0x00000000 \"}}'",
    "stack": "---------------------------------------------------------------------------
XMLSyntaxError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
File c:\\Users\\T\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\zeep\\loader.py:50, in parse_xml(content, transport, base_url, settings)
     49 try:
---> 50     elementtree = fromstring(content, parser=parser, base_url=base_url)
     51     docinfo = elementtree.getroottree().docinfo

File src\\\\lxml\\\\etree.pyx:3307, in lxml.etree.fromstring()

File src\\\\lxml\\\\parser.pxi:1989, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument()

File src\\\\lxml\\\\parser.pxi:1876, in lxml.etree._parseDoc()

File src\\\\lxml\\\\parser.pxi:1164, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDoc()

File src\\\\lxml\\\\parser.pxi:633, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc()

File src\\\\lxml\\\\parser.pxi:743, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult()

File src\\\\lxml\\\\parser.pxi:672, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError()

XMLSyntaxError: Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1 (<string>, line 1)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

XMLSyntaxError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
File c:\\Users\\T\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\zeep\\wsdl\\bindings\\soap.py:204, in SoapBinding.process_reply(self, client, operation, response)
    203 try:
--> 204     doc = parse_xml(content, self.transport, settings=client.settings)
    205 except XMLSyntaxError as exc:

File c:\\Users\\T\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\zeep\\loader.py:66, in parse_xml(content, transport, base_url, settings)
     65 except etree.XMLSyntaxError as exc:
---> 66     raise XMLSyntaxError(
     67         \"Invalid XML content received (%s)\" % exc.msg, content=content
     68     )

XMLSyntaxError: Invalid XML content received (Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TransportError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[48], line 1
----> 1 клиент.Справочники.ВидыНоменклатуры.НайтиПоНименованию(\"Товары\")

File c:\\Users\\T\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\brom.py:3065, in ОбъектыМенеджер.__getattr__(self, item)
   3064 def __getattr__(self, item):
-> 3065     return self.__tryget(item)

File c:\\Users\\T\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\brom.py:3043, in ОбъектыМенеджер.__tryget(self, name)
   3042 def __tryget(self, name):
-> 3043     метаданные = self._moduleMetadata.Найти(name)
   3044     if метаданные:
   3045         if self.__collectionType == ТипКоллекции.Справочник:

File c:\\Users\\T\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\brom.py:242, in УзелМетаданных.Найти(self, имя)
    240 результат = self;
    241 for текИмя in имена:
--> 242     узел = результат.НайтиПодчиненный(текИмя)
    243     if узел:
    244         результат = узел

File c:\\Users\\T\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\brom.py:870, in МетаданныеКоллекция.НайтиПодчиненный(self, имя)
    867     if node != None:
    868         return ПостроительМетаданных.ПолучитьУзелИзSOAP(node, self)
--> 870 именаПодчиненных = self.ИменаПодчиненных()
    871 for текИмя in именаПодчиненных:
    872     if текИмя.lower() == имя.lower():

File c:\\Users\\T\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\brom.py:846, in МетаданныеКоллекция.ИменаПодчиненных(self)
    843         self.__childrenNames = имена
    844         return self.__childrenNames
--> 846 картаИмен = self.Корень().ПолучитьИменаОбъектовКоллекций(self.Путь())
    847 имена = картаИмен[self.Путь()]
    848 if not имена == None:

File c:\\Users\\T\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\brom.py:998, in МетаданныеКонфигурация.ПолучитьИменаОбъектовКоллекций(self, коллекции)
    997 def ПолучитьИменаОбъектовКоллекций(self, коллекции):
--> 998     result = self.__bromClient.SoapКлиент.service.GetMetadaChildrenNames(коллекции)
    999     return self.__bromClient.Сериализатор().ИзЗначенияБром(result)

File c:\\Users\\T\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\zeep\\proxy.py:46, in OperationProxy.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     43 if soap_headers:
     44     kwargs[\"_soapheaders\"] = soap_headers
---> 46 return self._proxy._binding.send(
     47     self._proxy._client,
     48     self._proxy._binding_options,
     49     self._op_name,
     50     args,
     51     kwargs,
     52 )

File c:\\Users\\T\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\zeep\\wsdl\\bindings\\soap.py:135, in SoapBinding.send(self, client, options, operation, args, kwargs)
    132 if client.settings.raw_response:
    133     return response
--> 135 return self.process_reply(client, operation_obj, response)

File c:\\Users\\T\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\zeep\\wsdl\\bindings\\soap.py:206, in SoapBinding.process_reply(self, client, operation, response)
    204     doc = parse_xml(content, self.transport, settings=client.settings)
    205 except XMLSyntaxError as exc:
--> 206     raise TransportError(
    207         \"Server returned response (%s) with invalid XML: %s.\
Content: %r\"
    208         % (response.status_code, exc, response.content),
    209         status_code=response.status_code,
    210         content=response.content,
    211     )
    213 # Check if this is an XOP message which we need to decode first
    214 if message_pack:

TransportError: Server returned response (400) with invalid XML: Invalid XML content received (Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1).
Content: b'\\xef\\xbb\\xbf{\"#exception\":\"{http://v8.1c.ru/8.1/data/core}Exception\",\"exception\":{\"clsid\":\"a01f465c-ed70-442e-ada5-847668d7a41c\",\"descr\":\"\\xd0\\x94\\xd0\\xbe\\xd1\\x81\\xd1\\x82\\xd0\\xb8\\xd0\\xb3\\xd0\\xbd\\xd1\\x83\\xd1\\x82\\xd0\\xbe \\xd0\\xbe\\xd0\\xb3\\xd1\\x80\\xd0\\xb0\\xd0\\xbd\\xd0\\xb8\\xd1\\x87\\xd0\\xb5\\xd0\\xbd\\xd0\\xb8\\xd0\\xb5 \\xd1\\x83\\xd1\\x87\\xd0\\xb5\\xd0\\xb1\\xd0\\xbd\\xd0\\xbe\\xd0\\xb9 \\xd0\\xb2\\xd0\\xb5\\xd1\\x80\\xd1\\x81\\xd0\\xb8\\xd0\\xb8\\\
\\xd0\\x94\\xd0\\xbe\\xd1\\x81\\xd1\\x82\\xd0\\xb8\\xd0\\xb3\\xd0\\xbd\\xd1\\x83\\xd1\\x82\\xd0\\xbe \\xd0\\xbf\\xd1\\x80\\xd0\\xb5\\xd0\\xb4\\xd0\\xb5\\xd0\\xbb\\xd1\\x8c\\xd0\\xbd\\xd0\\xbe\\xd0\\xb5 \\xd0\\xba\\xd0\\xbe\\xd0\\xbb\\xd0\\xb8\\xd1\\x87\\xd0\\xb5\\xd1\\x81\\xd1\\x82\\xd0\\xb2\\xd0\\xbe \\xd0\\xbf\\xd0\\xbe\\xd0\\xb4\\xd0\\xba\\xd0\\xbb\\xd1\\x8e\\xd1\\x87\\xd0\\xb5\\xd0\\xbd\\xd0\\xb8\\xd0\\xb9 \\xd0\\xba \\xd0\\x98\\xd0\\x91\",\"data\":\"77u/ew0Ke2EwMWY0NjVjLWVkNzAtNDQyZS1hZGE1LTg0NzY2OGQ3YTQxYywi0JTQ\\\\r\\\
vtGB0YLQuNCz0L3Rg9GC0L4g0L7Qs9GA0LDQvdC40YfQtdC90LjQtSDRg9GH0LXQ\\\\r\\\
sdC90L7QuSDQstC10YDRgdC40LgNCtCU0L7RgdGC0LjQs9C90YPRgtC+INC/0YDQ\\\\r\\\
tdC00LXQu9GM0L3QvtC1INC60L7Qu9C40YfQtdGB0YLQstC+INC/0L7QtNC60LvR\\\\r\\\
jtGH0LXQvdC40Lkg0Log0JjQkSIsDQp7MDAwMDAwMDAtMDAwMC0wMDAwLTAwMDAt\\\\r\\\
MDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwfSwiYmFja2VuZHQuZGxsOjB4MDAwMDZERDYgYmFja2VuZHQu\\\\r\\\
ZGxsOjB4MDA1OEMxQUUgYmFja2VuZHQuZGxsOjB4MDA1OEFERUYgdnJzYmFzZXQu\\\\r\\\
ZGxsOjB4MDAwMTgwQjQgdnJzYmFzZXQuZGxsOjB4MDAwMTcwMTMgdnJzYmFzZXQu\\\\r\\\
ZGxsOjB4MDAwMTY3MUUgdnJzYmFzZXQuZGxsOjB4MDAxMUZDRkUgdnJzYmFzZXQu\\\\r\\\
ZGxsOjB4MDAxMjBEQkUgdnJzYmFzZXQuZGxsOjB4MDAwNERFODMgdnJzYmFzZXQu\\\\r\\\
ZGxsOjB4MDAwMTMwODMgdnJzYmFzZXQuZGxsOjB4MDAwNTYxNzYgdnJzYmFzZXQu\\\\r\\\
ZGxsOjB4MDAwNEIyMDkgdnJzYmFzZXQuZGxsOjB4MDAwNTY0QTQgdnJzYmFzZXQu\\\\r\\\
ZGxsOjB4MDAwNTZFODkgY29yZTgzdC5kbGw6MHgwMDI3Q0EyMCBjb3JlODN0LmRs\\\\r\\\
bDoweDAwMjdDQTgyIGNvcmU4M3QuZGxsOjB4MDAxNThFMzQgdWNydGJhc2UuZGxs\\\\r\\\
OjB4MDAwMDAwMDAgS0VSTkVMMzIuRExMOjB4MDAwMDAwMDAgdW5rbm93bjoweDAw\\\\r\\\
MDAwMDAwIHVua25vd246MHgwMDAwMDAwMCAiLCIwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAw\\\\r\\\
MDAwMDAwIiwwMDAwMDAwMC0wMDAwLTAwMDAtMDAwMC0wMDAwMDAwMDAwMDB9LDM5\\\\r\\\
fQ==\",\"category\":\"0000000000000000000000000\",\"creationStack\":\"backendt.dll:0x00006DD6 backendt.dll:0x0058C1AE backendt.dll:0x0058ADEF vrsbaset.dll:0x000180B4 vrsbaset.dll:0x00017013 vrsbaset.dll:0x0001671E vrsbaset.dll:0x0011FCFE vrsbaset.dll:0x00120DBE vrsbaset.dll:0x0004DE83 vrsbaset.dll:0x00013083 vrsbaset.dll:0x00056176 vrsbaset.dll:0x0004B209 vrsbaset.dll:0x000564A4 vrsbaset.dll:0x00056E89 core83t.dll:0x0027CA20 core83t.dll:0x0027CA82 core83t.dll:0x00158E34 ucrtbase.dll:0x00000000 KERNEL32.DLL:0x00000000 unknown:0x00000000 unknown:0x00000000 \"}}'"
}


Судя по всему этот "Brom" уже давно не поддерживается и не развивается. По-моему, использовать его сомнительно.
